# when i create a apk in android its give me error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, apk

**Error msg:**

```
> Configure project :lottie-react-native
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-android-0.71.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not download react-android-0.71.3-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3)
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.3/react-android-0.71.3-release.aar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.3/react-android-0.71.3-release.aar'.
               > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

**path :<project name><android><app>**

this path I'm run this cmd to create a key store file

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore NewsApp.keystore -alias NewsApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then after open `<android><app><build.gradle>` this file and add this line

```
  signingConfigs {
         release {
            storeFile file('NewsApp.keystore')
            storePassword 'NewsApp123'
            keyAlias 'NewsApp'
            keyPassword 'NewsApp123'
        }
    }
```

and this line

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
           .....
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           .....
        }
    }
```

then save file and go to terminal and go to android folder with this cmd

```
cd android
```

then run this cmd to creat reles apk file

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

then it's take some time then it will give me error I don't know where is my mistek

anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you tried to clear gradlew?

Comment: using this cmd `cd android &&./gradlew clean`

Comment: are you getting same error?

Comment: yesh i getting same

Comment: Try to open android directory in android studio and check are you able to run the app?

Comment: okay i will try